# optimizing CSS 720*1280 mobile devices

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, viewport, mobile-devices

I'm trying to optimize my webpage to 720*1200 mobile devices: 
[My page](http://teeg.hu/mobile/bejelentkezes.aspx)

It works perfectly on 320*480 and 480*800 devices, but not on 720*1200.
The page loads zoomed in, 
just like the layout viewport would be 720*1030 but the visual viewport would be 360*515.

I've set the viewport tag, but it hasn't any effect.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=false" />
<title>teeg bejelentkezes</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-device-width:720px)" href="css/style-720.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width:719px) and (max-width:719px) and (min-device-width:480px) and (min-width:480px)" href="css/style.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width:479px) and (max-width:479px)" href="css/style-320.css" />
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answers, i've tried Matt Coughlin's suggestion, but the AVD (720*1280) included the 480px css instead of 720. In the end I switched my approach and i changed my design to responsive. [RWD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design)
and [Examples](http://www.awwwards.com/50-examples-of-responsive-web-design.html)

Answer (score 2):

**Recommendation:**

- Use `min-width` and `max-width` in the media queries.
- Avoid using `min-device-width` and `max-device-width`.

**Viewport meta tag:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Add `minimum-scale`, `maximum-scale`, or `user-scalable` if needed.

**Media queries:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      media="only screen and (min-width:720px)"
      href="css/style-720.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      media="only screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:719px)"
      href="css/style.css" /> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      media="only screen and (max-width:479px)"
      href="css/style-320.css" />
```

**Explanation:**

`min-width` and `max-width` are easier to work with than `min-device-width` and `max-device-width`. Using all 4 of them may result in media queries that will not be applied in some cases, since the two sets of values do not always match.

On iOS devices, `min-device-width` and `max-device-width` act on the width in landscape mode, regardless of orientation, while `min-width` and `max-width` act on the width of the current orientation.

Also, on Android devices, `min-device-width` and `max-device-width` correspond to physical pixels, while `min-width` and `max-width` correspond to dips (device-independent pixels), which makes it easier to work with devices with a variety of pixel densities.

[The Boston Globe](http://bostonglobe.com/), the best example of adaptive-content responsive design, works almost entirely on `min-width` and `max-width`.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0
```

Comment: locking the users zooming-options is mostly a bad idea.